# Return a response entity on this method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this method that needs a valid return response but I couldn't figure it out on how can I implement it.

```
    @Override 
    public List<ReportLogsDataEntity> generateHtmlSummaryReport() 
            throws Exception {

        HtmlTag rootElem = new HtmlParentElement("<html>");
        rootElem.setStartTag("<html>");
        rootElem.setEndTag("</html>");

        HtmlTag headElem = new HtmlParentElement("<head>");
        headElem.setStartTag("<head>");
        headElem.setEndTag("</head>");

        // CSS STYLE FOR TABLE
        HtmlTag styleElem = new HtmlParentElement("<style>");
        styleElem.setStartTag("<style> table {\n"
                + "  border-collapse: collapse;\n" + "  width: 50%;\n" + "}\n"
                + "\n" + "th {background-color:#D98880;}\n" + "\n" + "th, td {\n"
                + "  font-family: Verdana;\n"
                + "  font-size: 15px;\n" + "  padding: 8px;\n"
                + "  text-align: center;\n" + "  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;\n"
                + "}\n" + "\n" + "tr:hover {background-color:#f5f5f5;}\n");
        styleElem.setEndTag("</style>");

        HtmlTag bodyElem = new HtmlParentElement("<body>");
        bodyElem.setStartTag("<body>");
        bodyElem.setEndTag("</body>");

        HtmlTag tableElem = new HtmlParentElement("<table>");
        tableElem.setStartTag("<center><table>");
        tableElem.setEndTag("</table></center>");

        HtmlTag tHeader = addTableHeader();

        List<HtmlTag> tDataSummaryLogs = addSummaryLogs();
        tableElem.addChildTag(tHeader);

        // SETTING THE TABLE TO BE USED TO POPULATE
        // WITH SUMMARY LOGS DATA
        tDataSummaryLogs.forEach(tableElem::addChildTag);

        // CONSTRUCTING THE WHOLE HTML ELEMENTS
        headElem.addChildTag(styleElem);
        bodyElem.addChildTag(tableElem);
        rootElem.addChildTag(headElem);
        rootElem.addChildTag(bodyElem);

        log.info(rootElem.generateHtml());

        writeToHTMLFile(rootElem.generateHtml());

        return null;

    }
```

I am quite lost on how can I implement or way to change the `return null` into a return `ResponseEntity`? Or any valid return in this method? Or like a response when `generateHtmlSummaryReport()` has been successful? Any help or insights is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added response in form of ResponseEntity

```
@Override 
public ResponseEntity<String> generateHtmlSummaryReport() 
        throws Exception {
 ........//your code
 return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

or if you want to add headers and body to your response then do this

```
 return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .header("Custom-Header", "foo")
    .body("Custom header set");
```